# Move existing pages into newly created pages with TYPO3 DataHandler

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x, datahandler

I am using the DataHandler to create and move pages like in this snippet. While new pages are created fine, existing subpages are not moved into their newly created parents.

### This creates the new page but does not move the existing page

```php
$data = [
    'pages' => [ 
        'NEW_IT' => [
            'pid' => 1,
            'hidden' => false,
            'title' => 'IT',
        ],
        591 => [
            // this is not set
            'pid' => 'NEW_IT', 
            // but this is set
            'title' => 'I am a child of IT', 
        ],
    ]
];
```

I tried `['pages'][591]['move'] = 'NEW_IT'` but also to no avail.

I also tried `'591'` instead of `591`, `dataHandler->reverseOrder = true` and `dataHandler->copyTree = true`.

`dataHandler->errorLog` is empty.

### In contrary, this works (new page into new page)

```php
$data = [
    'pages' => [ 
        'NEW_IT' => [
            'pid' => 1,
            'hidden' => false,
            'title' => 'IT',
        ],
        'NEW_IT_SUB' => [
            'pid' => 'NEW_IT',
        ],
    ]
];
```

Also I wonder which IDs (`NEW<any string>` vs. `NEW<base64>` etc.) are acceptable as I did not find anything in the documentation and the examples use different styles. The "must be unique" is obvious. But I don't get why some people generate UUIDs there.

### References

- https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/9.5/en-us/ApiOverview/Typo3CoreEngine/Database/Index.html

EDIT: I opened a forge ticket: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/90939

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked the code / DataHandler in v8/v9 and master. The corresponding logic in the DataHandler has not changed for that.

I have created a test case and xdebugged through it, also i was pretty sure after looking into the code, what happens. But have done this to validate that **"it is working the way i think the code tells"** - although it is not the way you expected. And I'm too. Remembering that I had such an issue last year through a migration script, but did not digged deeper into it (because of time), i changed it and made this as loops.

Creating page => retrieving the replaced id => using it for the other data commands.

The datahandler loops through each record for a table in the provided dataset array.

```
foreach ($this->datamap[$table] as $id => $incomingFieldArray) { ... }
```

First it prepares some stuff, and calling registered `processDatamap_preProcessFieldArray` hooks, it checks the given **$id**

```
// Is it a new record? (Then Id is a string)
if (!MathUtility::canBeInterpretedAsInteger($id)) { ... } else { ... }
```

If the id is not an integer or an integer string, it executed the true-branch, otherwise the false-branch. So long, so good.

The TRUE-Branch handles creating a new record (page, tt_content, ...), adding the replacement for the provided NEWxxx as substituion and so on.

It also checks, if a  'pid' field is in the record, and if it contains with NEW. If it is so, it replaces NEWxxx with the uid of the previously created record.

On the otherhand, if $id is not a integer or a integer string, it assumes it is an existing record. (FALSE-Branch). On this branch there is no checking for 'pid', if it contains NEW and looking up for replacement.

But .. why is there no error ? If it did not replace it, it should crash or someting like that ? - Yes, that is what we would assume - at least for that.

'pid' is always ignored in appling to the record ( see method `fillInFieldArray()` )

```
switch ($field) {
    case 'uid':
    case 'pid':
         // Nothing happens, already set
         break;
  ...
}
```

and so .. as long as you do not provide further fields/values in the second page array ( that with the integer id and the pid with NEW from the initial), it has nothing to do. Nothing to do is not an error - and so, it do nothing and even do not notify anything about it.

Is it a bug ? Don't know, personally I would say yes. But maybe this should be created as an issue, and eventually discussed with the core developer/other contributers.

Maybe there were/are reasons WHY it only do this one run.

Either the documentation should be changed to make clear, that 'pid' replacement only works, id $id => [] is also a new / playholder id .. or you have to do it in 2 rounds.

Or .. put as as feature/bug to the issue tracker, and let's discuss it. And maybe giv it a try to implement it in the FALSE/existing record branch too. But let's heare some other opionons about it.

If others thing this should be also be done for the existing records in the same round, I would take the time tommorrow/at the weekend to provide an patch for it / the issue. (Would be fun to fight with the datahandler ).